# Hyperref and ntheorem's thref: inconsistent numbering

Tags: hyperref, theorems, incompatibility, ntheorem

When using `ntheorem` with the `thref` option to get the named reference command `\thref`, sometimes the theorem numbers produced is "different" from the theorem numbers produced by just `\ref`. Any suggestions on fixes/workarounds?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[standard,amsmath,thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

\numberwithin{Theorem}{section}

\begin{document}
\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chaptername}
\section{Test}
\begin{Theorem}\label{test1} Test theorem
\end{Theorem}

Cite with ref: \ref{test1}

Cite with thref: \thref{test1}
\end{document}
```

Which compiles to

[image: Buggy output]

Notice in particular that the `\thref` output shows Theorem 1.1.1.1, the first (extra) 1 belonging to the `\part`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[standard,amsmath,thref]{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

\numberwithin{Theorem}{section}

\begin{document}
\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chaptername}
\section{Test}
\begin{Theorem}\label{test1} Test theorem
\end{Theorem}

Cite with ref: \ref{test1}

Cite with thref: \thref{test1}
\end{document}
```

Without using hyperref, however, everything looks fine:

[image: Output that I want]

---

**Remarks**

Without the `\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}` line, the output is okay. However, I need the `\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}` because for this thing I am working on I want the chapter numbers to be within individual parts, and without explicitly setting this, `hyperref` fouls up and gets confused between equation 1.1.1 of part 1 and equation 1.1.1 of part 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think I understand: how can your reader distinguish between Theorem 1.1.1 in Part 1 from Theorem 1.1.1 in Part 2?

The following hack seems to work, but, like every hack, it might have unexpected consequences.

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\def\thm@fmt@hyplabel@ii#1.#2.#3{#3}
\makeatother
```

In order to get correct hyperlinks, `\thref` doesn't use `\theTheorem`, but the more complex `\theHTheorem`, which is set up by `hyperref`. This representation of the internal counter `HTheorem` (which is synchronized with `Theorem`) *must* take into account the part number or wrong and duplicate links would be produced.

The hack consists in modifying the definition of `\thm@fmt@hyplabel` that's usually defined as `\def\thm@fmt@hyplabel@ii#1.#2{#2}` and put in front of the internal reference produced by `hyperref`: in the "normal" case this would be

```
Theorem.<chapter>.<section>.<theorem>
```

but with your setting it is

```
Theorem.<part>.<chapter>.<section>.<theorem>
```

Thus the normal definition of `\thm@fmt@hyplabel` is producing the part number, while you want the chapter number; hence the modified definition.

Comment: to distinguish Theorem 1.1.1 in Part 1 and Theorem 1.1.1 in Part 2, I am using `smartref`'s `\partref` command. I have a macro set-up such that citing theorems in the same part of the book will generate "Theorem 1.1.1", whereas citing theorems in a different part of the book will generate "Part II, Theorem 1.1.1". Since there aren't very many cross-part references, this can help make the text slightly more readable.

Comment: Does the hack work with your macros?

Comment: Looks like nothing broke! (Just tried both pdf and dvi versions.) So it looks like it works. Thanks. I will leave this open for a little bit just to get some eyes on it. Otherwise I'll accept this answer later today.

Comment: What I am confused about is why the difference introduced by `hyperref`?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the update. I see how it works now.